# I am working on Azure Functions and trying to test by mocking my MongoDB. Help me to run my test successfully

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, junit, azure-functions

Exception I am getting

Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'csoKpiBlobTriggerFunction' of type 'class com.stellantis.cso.kpi.function.CsoKpiBlobTriggerFunction'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "connectionString" is null

```
@Mock
MongoCollection mockCollection;

@Mock
MongoClient mongoClient;

@Mock
MongoDatabase database;

@InjectMocks
CsoKpiBlobTriggerFunction csoKpiBlobTriggerFunction;


@InjectMocks
ExecutionContextMock executionContext;




@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Test
void TestRun() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("/src/test/resources/json/10Q3EG1421896.json");
    byte[] arr = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    
    Mockito.when(mongoClient.getDatabase(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(database);
    
    Mockito.when(database.getCollection(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockCollection);
    

    csoKpiBlobTriggerFunction.run(arr,"10Q3EG1421896.json",executionContext);
    //PowerMockito.whenNew(MongoClient.class).withArguments(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(mongoClient);
    //PowerMockito.whenNew(MongoClientURI.class).withArguments(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any()).thenReturn(Mockito.any());
    //PowerMockito.whenNew(ConnectionString.class).withArguments("mongodb://").thenReturn(Mockito.any());
    
    
}
```